# Multiple IF statements wont work?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am working on some code that turns a month in to its number.

```
$postdate = "09:24:33 Mar 07, 2014 PST";

//SPLIT UP DATE
$hour = substr("$postdate", 0, -23);
$min = substr("$postdate", 3, -20);
$sec = substr("$postdate", 6, -17);
$month = substr("$postdate", 9, -13);
$day = substr("$postdate", 13, -10);
$year = substr("$postdate", 17, -4); 

//SET MONTH TO NUMBER
if($month = "Jan") {$month = 01;}
if($month = "Feb") {$month = 02;}
if($month = "Mar") {$month = 03;} 
if($month = "Apr") {$month = 04;} 
if($month = "May") {$month = 05;} 
if($month = "Jun") {$month = 06;}
if($month = "Jul") {$month = 07;} 
if($month = "Aug") {$month = 08;} 
if($month = "Sep") {$month = 09;}
if($month = "Oct") {$month = 10;} 
if($month = "Nov") {$month = 11;} 
if($month = "Dec") {$month = 12;} 

//Display Month
month: <?php echo $month ?>
```

Why won't this work? It works fine if I only use one statement. Also, am I going the long way round here? Is there already a function that will turn a month in to its number?

Thanks.

Comment: echo (new (\DateTime())->format('m');

Comment: Basic PHP syntax: `=` performs assignments. `==` does comparisons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need comparison not assignment

ie `==` not `=`

So the first line should be

if ($month == "Jan") {$month = 01;}

better still use a associative list

Comment: Better still, use the correct formatting character: `date('m')` as shown in John's answer :) (not my DV, btw)

Comment: I would be interesting in why the DV?

Answer (score 5):

Way more complicated than it needs to be:

```
echo date('m', strtotime("09:24:33 Mar 07, 2014 PST"));
// Output: 03
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LhWEYT)

Answer (score 4):

You are using = where you should use == (Or === if $month is a string) in your if statements.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a native class called [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) that can do almost all operations with dates you want. You should take a look on its methods and how to use them, it is everything documented on PHP site and it will do the job for you.